# Android CursorIndexOutOfBoundException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

I'm getting a cursor Index Out Of Bound exception when I shouldn't, I did it exactly how it should be done using

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst)
```

My code is shown below

```
Log.w("colum3", String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        //final Uri id = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
                        //Log.d("PRINT3:", id.toString());
                        String link = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("token_id"));
                        String URL_Update = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/add.json?token=" + link;
                        Log.d("Sync Url3:", URL_Update);
                        StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST ,URL_Update, 
                                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        try {

                                            provider.delete(uri, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")), null);
                                            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);

                                        } catch (RemoteException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        Log.e("str Response3:", response);
                                    }

                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }


                        }){
                            @Override
                            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                params.put("device_id",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("device_id")));
                                params.put("latitude",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lat")));
                                params.put("longitude", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("long")));
                                params.put("time", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("time")));
                     Log.d("Parameter3", params.toString());
                                return params;
                            }
                        };

                        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
                        cursor.moveToNext();
                    } while (cursor.isAfterLast());
                }
```

And the Funny thing there is that it shows the output in the Log here

```
final Uri id = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
                            Log.d("PRINT3:", id.toString());
                            String link = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("token_id"));
                            String URL_Update = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/add.json?token=" + link;
                            Log.d("Sync Url3:", URL_Update);
```

I read **Cursor** in **Google Android Documentation** and I'm doing it right, but I still don't seem to know what's going on wrong. And it happens only when there's just one data in the Sqlite database.

My Log is below

```
09-05 20:52:37.245: E/AndroidRuntime(5152): FATAL EXCEPTION: SyncAdapterThread-1
09-05 20:52:37.245: E/AndroidRuntime(5152): Process: com.deliveryscience.track:sync, PID: 5152
09-05 20:52:37.245: E/AndroidRuntime(5152): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1
09-05 20:52:37.245: E/AndroidRuntime(5152):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java)
09-05 20:52:37.245: E/AndroidRuntime(5152):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java)
09-05 20:52:37.245: E/AndroidRuntime(5152):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java)
09-05 20:52:37.245: E/AndroidRuntime(5152):     at com.deliveryscience.track.services.SyncAdapter.sendData(SyncAdapter.java:224)
09-05 20:52:37.245: E/AndroidRuntime(5152):     at com.deliveryscience.track.services.SyncAdapter.onPerformSync(SyncAdapter.java:51)
09-05 20:52:37.245: E/AndroidRuntime(5152):     at android.content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter$SyncThread.run(AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.java)
09-05 20:52:37.526: E/Volley(5152): [80521] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1
09-05 20:52:37.526: E/Volley(5152): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1
09-05 20:52:37.526: E/Volley(5152):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java)
09-05 20:52:37.526: E/Volley(5152):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java)
09-05 20:52:37.526: E/Volley(5152):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java)
09-05 20:52:37.526: E/Volley(5152):     at com.deliveryscience.track.services.SyncAdapter$9.getParams(SyncAdapter.java:257)
09-05 20:52:37.526: E/Volley(5152):     at com.android.volley.Request.getBody(Request.java:433)
09-05 20:52:37.526: E/Volley(5152):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:236)
09-05 20:52:37.526: E/Volley(5152):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:210)
09-05 20:52:37.526: E/Volley(5152):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:106)
09-05 20:52:37.526: E/Volley(5152):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:93)
09-05 20:52:37.526: E/Volley(5152):     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:110)
```

Any help would be appreciated, I've asked the Question once and couldn't find any answer, just trying again if anyone can help out

Comment: try `do{ }while(cursor.moveToNext())`

Comment: See my answer and let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access element 1 (the second since it's zero-based) when the size is only one.

You have a problem with the way you're detecting the end of the data set.
Your cursor won't become null after you've processed the last row.
You need to detect the end of the data set in a different way.

You could use this mechanism:

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
    ....
    cursor.moveToNext();
}
```

Comment: Works fine, but I had to move my **HashMap** up and I can't access the cursor after the Request cause I need to delete that Row after sending the data

Answer (score 0):

`cursor.moveToFirst` takes you to the first (and only in this case) result. The next call to `cursor.moveToNext` takes you to the second result (index 1) which doesn't exist.

So do the following while checking for last row

```
while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

cursor.moveToNext();
}
```

`isAfterLast()`returns whether the cursor is pointing to the position after the last row.Hence by doing like above you are making sure that if the cursor is not pointing to the position after the last row, then only move to the next row of cursor.

**Edit**

Remove this `if` statement from your code

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst){
}
```

Instead just use

```
cursor.moveToFirst;
while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

cursor.moveToNext();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this 2 lines

```
cursor.moveToNext();
        } while (cursor.isAfterLast());
```

With

```
While(cursor.hasNext())
```

> And move cursor.moveTNext() after the do { instruction

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    // some stuff here
                    cursor.moveToNext();
                } while (cursor.isAfterLast());
            }
```

to

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()){
  // do the stuff here
}
```

cursor.moveToNext() method will return true if next is exist and return false if not exist.